# How to contact specific pypi server using Chef and python_pip

Tags: python, chef-infra

We're running our own PyPi server.  Now we're starting to use Chef to handle deployments.  I'm trying to figure out the best approach to pip install from within a Chef recipe, contacting our custom server and passing credentials.

Typically we would intall packages like this:

```
pip install -i http://<server address:portno>/simple extremely_cool_package
```

The server prompts for username and password. The server speaks basic access authentication since it's behind our firewall.

Can python_pip do all this, and if so how?  If not, what's the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following isn't optimal, but it gets the job done:

```
python_pip "extremely_cool_package" do
     action :install
     options "--index-url=http://username:password@server address:portno/simple"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem when trying to install from a pip repository.

The easiest way is to introduce your credentials `~/.pip/pip.conf` in the form:

```
[global]
index-url = http://user:password@server_address:portno/simple
```

You can also put `pip.conf` in the root of your virtualenv folder and use `pip install` inside the virtualenv session.

Edit:

In order of avoiding your default pip library being replaced by the new one you should use

```
[global]
extra-index-url = http://user:password@server_address:portno/simple
```

Comment: The line with `index-url = ...` should not be commented out - should it ?